# mongodb connection error with node and express

Tags: jhipster-registry

mongodb connection error with node and express.
The error:

```
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:206:19) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.clustr0-a1rol.mongodb.net'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible issues with this case:

- Check your IP address is whitelisted with your MongoDB client
- Check your connection URI once again to check the possible error with that.

Please check this other problem and solution. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60696749/connect-nodejs-to-mongodb-droplet/60696974#60696974)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, whatever I done is:

1. restart my node server.
2. change my database user.
3. change my network and waiting sometime.
4. then tried to connect.
5. this time mongo connection was fine.

N.B- you can check your connection URI too, if its ok. then try with a different network.