# Unable to establish a mongodb atlas connection

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

I've tried connecting a MongoDB cloud atlas using URL in my Node application,but getting the following error:-
**UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster0-coypu.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:206:19)**

Ive connected using:-

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || config.connectionString, { useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true  });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

In order to check whether the connection is established or not ive donw using:-

```
mongoose.connect('config.connectionString',{
  useCreateIndex: true, 
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(
  () => {
    console.log("Database connection established!");
  },
  err => {
    console.log("Error connecting Database instance due to: ", err);
  }
);
```

where config.connectionString contains the URL generated in my atlas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mongoose
  .connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => {
    log.info("successfully connected to db");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    log.error("db connection failed " + err);
  });
```

Just make sure the URI is in correct format

Comment: I was using the uri directly which i got from the atlas.

Comment: please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60696749/connect-nodejs-to-mongodb-droplet/60696974#60696974)

Comment: Stil not able to get after changing the URI format.
After changing the URI format getting that the server could not be found

Comment: Can you share the uri format and not the actual uri

Comment: Actual one which I got from the MongoDB atlas:-

```mongodb+srv://<username>:<pass>@<host_name>/<collection_name>?retryWrites=true&w=majority&readPreference=secondary&ssl=true```

And the one which I've changed from your suggestion:-

```
mongodb://<username>:<password>@<host_name>:27017/<collection_name>?ssl=true&replicaSet=<hostname>&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority 
```

Comment: `mongodb://<username>:<pass>@host1:27017,host2:27017,host3:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=host&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority` you can see 3 different hosts on atlas, there is a fallback logic for connection. kindly try this

Comment: Another thing is in the network setting of atlas allow the IP you are connecting from.

Comment: Yes,I had whitelisted all ip addr by specifying 0.0.0.0/0